# what is equivalent to torch.nn.fold in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, torch

i want to convert torch.nn.fold function to tensorflow.

Is there any function just like nn.fold in tensorflow?
'''

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
z = F.fold(z, kernel_size=s, output_size=(H1, W1), stride=s)
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not equivalent but if you want only the sliding window feature, there are some functions related to it.

- https://www.tensorflow.org/text/api_docs/python/text/sliding_window
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dilation2d